# Regular space which is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I know that normality in the absence of $T_{1}$ does not imply regularity (Sierpinski space being a counterexample as it is vacuously normal but not regular). I have the feeling that similarly regularity in the absence of $T_{1}$ does not imply Hausdorff. I tried thinking of a counter example but obviously every such counter example mustn't be $T_{1}$ and I'm not familiar with many spaces which are not $T_{1}$ (the only ones that comes to mind are Trivial topologies and the Sierpinski space).

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$, and endow $X$ with the topology

$$\tau=\big\{\varnothing,\{0,1\},\{2,3\},X\big\}\;;$$

then $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is regular but not Hausdorff. ($X$ is homeomorphic to the product of the discrete two-point space with the indiscrete two-point space.)

**Added:** Given a space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, we can define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ by setting $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same open nbhds. If we identify equivalent points (i.e., take the quotient $X/\sim$), we always get a $T_0$-space. An $R_0$-*space* is one in which we get a $T_1$-space. As you can see, the example above is $R_0$: the quotient $X/\sim$ is just a discrete two-point space. You can start with any $T_3$-space and ‘fatten up’ some points to get an $R_0$, regular space that is not Hausdorff.

The [Wikipedia article on separation axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom#Main_definitions) has definitions of some of the more obscure ones, including $R_0$, as well as of the familiar ones.

Comment: The smallest example is the set $\{ 0, 1 \}$ with the indiscrete (trivial) topology. The space is obviously not $T_1$. It is, however, regular.

Comment: @dfeuer: True, but I wanted an example that wasn’t vacuously regular. (I could still have omitted the point $3$, of course, but I liked the more uniform construction.)

Comment: Interestingly, this $T_0$-space with the quotient map is universal in the sense that every map from $X$ to a $T_0$-space $Y$ factors uniquely through it :-)

Comment: It's not actually vacuous, technically speaking, because there is a closed set, $\varnothing$, and a point not in it, $0$. But certainly it is an uninformatively trivial example.

Comment: Very nice example Brian, as usual.
Somehow I completely overlooked the fact the trivial topology is  regular for some reason. Thanks to all repliers.

Comment: @Serpahimz: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sir   By the definition of hausdorff space  if we take two open set $ \{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ then $ \{0,1\}\cap\{2,3\} = \emptyset$ . then it will be hausdorff. Im not getting why it is not hausdorff ?

Comment: @jasmine: You’ve misunderstood the definition of *Hausdorff*. A Hausdorff space is one in which **every** pair of points have disjoint open neighborhoods. If this space were Hausdorff, there would be open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $0\in U$, $1\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$, and there are not: the only open sets that contain $0$ are $\{0,1\}$ and $X$, and both of them also contain $1$. This space isn’t even $T_1$: there is no open set that contains $0$ but not $1$. And since there is also no open set that contains $1$ but not $0$, this space isn’t even $T_0$.

Comment: okss got it now  sir @BrianM.Scott

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the textbook's definition of regular or normal, it may be required that the space is $T_1$ to begin with.  That would imply that for each $x\in X$, then $\{x\}$ must be closed...which would not be true in this specific example.  It truly depends on how regular or normal are defined.